# All Contents related to a content list

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, entities

Say a user has a list of  2 favorite books , one with taxonomy term "adventure" and one with taxonomy term "art". (n favorite books, related with m taxonomy terms)

How to automatically display a list of all books with taxonomy term "adventure" or "art" (or m taxonomy terms)

The steps could be :

- step 1 : build the list of the user's favorites books (views, flag, 
  filter : this is OK)
- step 2 : get the list of all taxonomy terms referenced by theses nodes,
- step 3 : get the list of all books referencing one or several of the taxonomy terms listed at step 2

My question is how to build a view which do these 3 steps.

Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, what have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks, I added details to my question. It's the first time I put a question on drupal.stackexchange and I am not used to the best pratices : Could you explain why did I get -1 for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) , build a view of content type book , then filter them based on taxonomy term , you even can expose the filter and let it to user to decide which genres want to view .

Comment: Thank you for helping, but the purpose is not having an exposed filter, the purpose is to automatically display related content (I edited my question). I know how to do it for content related to one single taxonomy term :(contextual filter on the taxonomy term), but I dont' know how to do it with all the taxonomy terms of all the favorites book of the user.

Comment: How have you stored a user's favorite books?

Comment: yes, I have stored it. and I have a view for the user's favorites books :list of content type "book" , with relationship "Flags : favorites(by current user, include only flagged content)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution with a chain of relationships :

In Views

Advanced : 
add a relationship "Flags" : favorites(by current user, include only flagged content) . set identifier to "favorite books"
add a relationship "Content: Book_category", relationship : "favorite books", check "Require this relationship). set identifier to "book category"
add a relationship : "Taxonomy term: Content using Book_category", relationship : "book category", check "Require this relationship. set identifier to "recommended books"

in Fields :

title, id,book, category etc with relationship : "recommended books"

Answer (score 0):

I know your solution is working but I think it might be a time consuming query , too many relationships . I suggest you another solution :

1. add a new field to users account (type : term reference and link it to your taxonomy vocabulary , I named it Favorite Genre)
2. Hide it from users using [Field Permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)
3. Install [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module
4. Enable flag actions sub-module
5. go to Rules and add new rule , event = A node has been flagged, under "your content type"
6. add an action , add an item to a list (we want to add the books genre to user's favorite)
7. item to be added is the flaged-node->book_catagory and that must be added to user-flagged-favorite_genre

by now when a user bookmark a book the book genre will be added to his/her favorite genre. the benefit is that there is no need for more querying to find this out.

now go to views add a relation based on user , and you can filter books based on user's favorite genre.

be careful : maybe you do a trick on  unbookmark , and remove the book genre from his list , this would be make mistake cause maybe user have other books with this genre . in this case you need to make a loop based on user's bookmarked books and check their genres , if there were no book with that genre then you can remove that genre from user's favorite .

more [details about Rules module here](https://drupalize.me/series/learning-rules-framework-series).